# Materials reacting to electric pulses

Tags: sensor, pulse, demodulation, materials

Do there exist materials that:
 - React to electrical pulses having frequency in the band 2-10Hz with a very low frequency response (near to DC), 
 - Have a measurable reaction, where measurable means that I can directly transduce the signal into an electrical one by connecting in some way the material to an electronic circuit,
 - The reaction is easy to measure, easy means that the measurement circuit is very elementary,
 - Dissipates very low power (microWatts (or orders about 10^2 microWatt ) if possible).

I actually don't care about the way these materials react, they can also emit some light whose spectrum varies with the pulses frequency.

Comment: Liquid crystals can do this, but they are not very easy to use.

Comment: Your "do not dissipate power ... do not allow any current to flow through them" requirement makes this difficult. To have a reaction, work is going to get done at some physical level, and that requires power to be used in some way. Otherwise you are asking for something with 'perpetual motion machine' properties (which is impossible). If you loosened that restriction, and indicated what level of power use you'd be willing to accept, then there may be answers. What are you trying to achieve? Is this a lab experiment, or a machine your trying to build?

Comment: There are many, of which the first which springs to mind is an inductor. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The OP says "do not dissipate power ... do not allow any current to flow through them"

Comment: Indeed; an inductor exposed to an externally applied electromagnetic pulse will have a voltage induced across its winding, but if it's not connected to anything no current will flow in it.

Comment: Maybe add that to your answer, because my 'knee jerk' was not that. Of course, to measure it, current will flow, but that could be tiny. I am currently assuming the OP doesn't mean "... do not allow any current to flow through them" but actually means a tiny amount of current flow is acceptable.

Comment: Yes I know I wrote an impossible requirement. Updated

Comment: Essentially I'm quite inexpert and the situation is: I have a sensor that gives a train of pulses when a certain event occurs. I need to "convert" these pulses in a stepwise signal saying "hey something is happening" and for various reasons I don't want a train of pulses but a stable signal that get high when the pulses show for a consistent amount of time (I don't want to do things for small duration events or for spurious pulses). 
I have then very strict power-current constraints (microA and microW). I thought that the information may be stored in the frequency content of the sensor output

Comment: [cond] thus some filtering may be ok. (or some digital counting). However I'm looking for crazy alternative ways that do not involve analog filtering circuits and this is the aim of this question.

Comment: Why you're looking for such a substance with so-many mathematical-specifications? What are you trying to do? could write in a bit  more clear and elaborate way?

Comment: Would a pressure-sensor work? piezo-electric disks from buzzers? Is there any electronic version of blood-pressure-check machine? what is used in that?

Comment: http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5789/handouts/piezo.pdf ... Would such thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example would be a chamber containing pure nitrobenzene with electrodes on either side. Applying an electric field causes a rotation of the polarization of light passing through the chamber. [Here's](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786447508641302?journalCode=tphm15) a reference to the original paper.

Since nitrobenzene is a dielectric, little current flows, and only a tiny amount of power is dissipated in the Kerr cell when the switching happens (due to losses in the dielectric). However the driving circuitry may well dissipate a fair bit of power if the switching occurs at a highly frequency.

Comment: Thanks, but an alternating electric field will cause an alternating polarization? (and therefore another oscillatory measurable phenomena?) Because if it is I obtain an oscillatory signal from an oscillatory signal and this is useless. Unless there's a very simple way to detect whether the light is changing its polarity, in this case I can recognize that there are oscillations in the original electri signal and the goal is reached

Comment: Yes, response is DC to high frequency. It's easy to detect by interposing polarizing filters which results in amplitude modulation of the transmitted light. There are crystals such as [KTP](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_titanyl_phosphate) which are more practical than liquids.

Comment: and what about signals at low frequency (1 to 5 Hz) ?

Comment: Yes, 1-5Hz is between DC and HF, so KTP etc will respond.